# Simple JavaScript library for DOM interactions

Tags: javascript, homework, dom

I got this pretty interesting homework assignment, which was to finish off a very simple Javascript library. I couldn't use jQuery.

First, I will show you the raw piece of code that I received, then I will show you my solution and the last piece of code is what I think is the test of all the functions I had to make. I checked it and it worked pretty well- I mean the console output was as expected. I would like to ask you whether my solution is okay or not.

What I was given:

```
'use strict';

var dom = {
    // TODO: fill in library's API ...

    create: function(tag_name, attrs){

    },

    // Attributes getter / setter 
    attr: function(elem, name, value){

    },

    // Append element as last child
    append: function(elem, child){

    },

    // Prepend element as first child
    prepend: function(elem, child){

    },

    // Detach element from dom
    remove: function(elem){

    }
}
```

What I did:

```
'use strict';

var dom = {
    // TODO: fill in library's API ...

    create: function(tag_name, attrs){
        var temp = document.createElement(tag_name);
        for(var key in attrs) 
            {
            temp.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
            }
        return temp;
    },

    // Attributes getter / setter 
    attr: function(elem, name, value){
        if(!value) return elem.getAttribute(name);
        elem.setAttribute(name,value);
        return elem;
    },

    // Append element as last child
    append: function(elem, child){
        elem.appendChild(child);
    },

    // Prepend element as first child
    prepend: function(elem, child){
        elem.prepend(child);
    },

    // Detach element from dom
    remove: function(elem){
        var par = elem.parentNode;
        par.removeChild(elem);
    }
}
```

WHAT I THINK IS A TEST:

```
'use strict';

describe('Dom library', function () {


  it('should allow to create dom elements', function () {
    var div = dom.create('div');

    expect(div instanceof window.Element).toBeTruthy();
    expect(div.tagName).toBe('DIV');
  });

  it('should allow to create dom elements with attributes', function () {
    var div = dom.create('div',{
        test:'test_value'
    });

    expect(div instanceof window.Element).toBeTruthy();
    expect(div.getAttribute('test')).toBe('test_value');
  });

  it('should allow to append elements', function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<div id="one"></div>\
    <div id="two"></div>\
    <div id="three"></div>';

    var appendee = document.createElement('div');
    dom.append(div, appendee)
    expect(div.children[div.children.length - 1]).toBe(appendee);
  });

  it('should allow to prepend elements', function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<div id="one"></div>\
    <div id="two"></div>\
    <div id="three"></div>';

    var prependee = document.createElement('div');
    dom.prepend(div, prependee)
    expect(div.children[0]).toBe(prependee);
  });

  it('should allow to detach elements', function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<div id="one"></div>\
    <div id="two"></div>\
    <div id="three"></div>';

    var target = div.children[0];
    var detached = dom.remove(target)
    expect(target).toBe(detached);
    expect(div.children[0]).not.toBe(target);
  });

  it('should allow get element attribute', function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute("test","test_value");

    expect(dom.attr(div, 'test')).toEqual('test_value');
  });

  it('should allow set element attribute', function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    dom.attr(div, 'test', 'test_value');

    expect(div.getAttribute('test')).toEqual('test_value');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, consider which browsers is this DOM library supposed to support. Then test that it works in all of them.

- `create()`

  - Plain for-in loop is not safe as it also loops over keys in object prototype.
  - `temp` is bad name for a variable.
  - You're repeatedly testing that return value is `window.Element`.
  - `window.Element` can be written as just `Element` (or perhaps use HTMLElement for clarity).
- `attr()`

  - What if the `value` is `0` or `""`?
- `prepend()`

  - `elem.prepend()` is not supported by all browsers.
- `remove()`

  - `par` is unnecessary abbreviation of `parent`.

A few general remarks:

- Check your code for consistent formatting. You're missing some semicolons and the indentation is inconsistent. Use a tool like ESLint.
- Escaping newlines to create multiline strings is not officially supported in ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1):

This is meant as a supplement for [Rene Saarsoo's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180728/simple-javascript-library-for-dom-interactions/180769#180769).

In general more testing and case handling could be a nice touch.

What happens if there is no `parentNode`? Or if the target isn't an instance of `HTMLElement`?

This is mostly a user-friendliness issue because it could be argued that the library should just be "used correctly", but it is something to keep in mind.

The snippet below shows some examples:

```js
'use strict';
var dom = {

  create: function(tag_name, attrs) {
    //Test for valid paramenters
    if (typeof tag_name === "string" ? tag_name.length < 1 : false)
      return;
    var temp = document.createElement(tag_name);
    if (attrs !== void 0) {
      for (var key in attrs) {
        //Needs test: attrs.hasOwnProperty(key)
        if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(key))
          temp.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
      }
    }
    return temp;
  },

  /* ... */

  remove: function(elem) {
    //Test for valid paramenters
    if (elem instanceof HTMLElement == false)
      return;
    var par = elem.parentNode;
    //What if parentNode is Null?
    if (par === null)
      return;
    par.removeChild(elem);
  }

};
```